# Blob vs. Blob Source in Google Apps Script

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, blob

I'm using [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) which lets you develop your Google Apps Script in typescript.

In my script, I convert a google sheet into a Blob of a PDF, then upload that to Google Drive.

The code runs fine, but I'm having trouble working with the [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob) vs. [BlobSource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source) types properly to keep TypeScript happy.

### Setup

I've declared some type abbreviations like this at the start of my file:

```
type Sheet = GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet;
type SS = GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Spreadsheet;
type GBlob = GoogleAppsScript.Base.Blob;
type GBlobSource = GoogleAppsScript.Base.BlobSource;
```

I have a a function with this signature:

```
getPdfBlob(sheet: Sheet, pdfName: string): GBlob
```

I do something like this in my code:

```
var pdfBlob = getPdfBlob(mySheet, 'aPdfName');
var file = DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob);
```

### Problem

My IDE complains that `DriveApp.createFile` wants type `BlobSource` as a parameter, not `Blob`.

If I try to casting Blob into BlobSource like this:

```
var file = DriveApp.createFile(<GBlobSource>pdfBlob);
```

My IDE complains:

> Conversion of type 'Blob' to type 'BlobSource' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
>
> Property 'getBlob' is missing in type 'Blob' but required in type 'BlobSource'.

As I mentioned, the code runs fine this way. I just want to get my type declarations correct so TypeScript continues to add value.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source) it looks like `Blob` *implements* `BlobSource` so I'm unsure why I can't "upcast" back to `BlobSource`. Could this be an error with the TypeScript definitions?

Any input on what the issue is here / the proper way to handle it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could certainly try modifying your local `.d.ts` files to reflect that Blob implements blobsource, and see if that resolves the issue. If so, make your PR to the DefinitelyTyped repo and fix it for everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

All what we need it's to implement `Class Blob` from `Interface BlobSource`. Replace [the row](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.base.d.ts#L13) with

`export interface Blob extends BlobSource {`

*Updates*

DefinitelyTyped was updated 
 for this https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/36279